# Dynamically change Icon of paper clip after a file is attached, to display a file icon instead.

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I'm currently trying to dynamically change my paper clip icon to a file icon when a document is attached. At the moment I have it show the file name on hover but I would like to have it show a different icon when a file is attached. I'm using C# along with JavaScript and jQuery.

I have a paper clip icon I can click which allows me to attach a file. After the file is attached, I want the icon to change from a paper clip to a file icon.

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="exception-modal-file-picker">
    <span class="widget-icon fa-2x float-right input input-file">
      <i class="fa fa-paperclip" id="paperclip"></i>
    </span>
</a>
<input type="file" class="hidden" id="fileDocument" name="fileDocument" onchange="document.getElementById('paperclip').title=value" />
```

Above I have the code for the paper clip which allows me to attach a file and on hover it show me the file name.

```
$('#exception-modal-file-picker').on('click', function() {
    $('#fileDocument').click();
});
```

Above is my JavaScript.

Comment: Hi - Welcome. Please consider reasing the FAQ and some other questions to learn how to ask more specific questions. Your question is extremely vague. Is this C#? HTML? CSS? Please provide a code snippet? :)  Please edit and update your question or risk it being closed promptly. Please don't take it personally. Thank you and Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to easily do this via `onChange`, You are currently only using the onChange to set the title. You could write a method to both set the title and change the icon.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: Thank you, i will give it a try.